# Prove for all point $(x_0,y_0)\not =(0,0)$ the restriction of $f$ to neighborhood $(x_0,y_0)$ have inverse.

Tags: analysis, inverse-function-theorem

Let $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$

Prove for all point $(x_0,y_0)\not =(0,0)$ the restriction of $f$ to neighborhood $(x_0,y_0)$ have inverse.

**My work:**

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$  defined by $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$
Let $(x_0,y_0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $(x_0,y_0)\not =(0,0)$
let go to see $f'(x_0,y_0)$ is invertible.

$$f'(x_0,y_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
\nabla f_1(x_0,y_o) \\
\nabla f_2(x_0,y_0)
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
2x_0 &-2y_0\\
2y_0 &  2x_0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $\det(f'(x_0,y_0))=4(x_0^2+y_0^2)\not =0$ this implies$f'(x_0,y_0))$ is invertible.

Let $U=?$ a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$. (By theorem of inverse function the exercise can be solved but i'm stuck defining the neighborhood $U$)

I am stuck here. Can someoe give me a hint?

Comment: If $\;(x,y)\neq (0,0)\;$ then there exists a complete neighborhood of $\;(x,y)\;$ which doesn't intersect the origin.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose w.l.o.g. that $\;x_0\neq0\;$ , then take $\;r:=\frac{|x_0|}2\;$ , and thus you can take

$$U:=B_{(x_0.y_0)}(r):=\text{ the open ball with center$\,(x_0,y_0)\,$ and radius}\;r$$

Comment: Why your take $r=frac{|x_0|}{2}$ ? Thanks

Comment: @Bvss12 Because I can...and that distance is half the distance of $\;x_0\;$ from zero, thus making sure the origin $\;(0,0)\;$ is **not** in $\;U\;$ ...